# App de react native no conecta con server API

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar con el siguiente problema:
Ya tengo montado mi server de nodeJS montado en un droplet de DigitalOcean, pero el problema reside en que al conectar la app al API server la primera vez que se usa la APP funciona todo normal pero ya si reinicio el server o cierro y vuelvo abrir la APP está ya no se conecta ni recibe ninguna respuesta del servidor, esto pasa tanto en modo DEBUG como en RELEASE. Ya le agregue el android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" al androdManifiest pero sigue sin funcionar. Lo raro es que al hacer las consultas al API server con postman si funciona, pero al realizarlas con la APP, no.
Pero si conecto la app al server api local de mi pc, trabaja sin problemas
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

```
const logIn = async () => {
if (login.email == "" || login.clave == "") {
  return setIsEmpty(true);
} else if (login.email != "" && login.clave != "") {
  if (haveEmailError) {
    return setErrorAlert(true);
  }
}

try {
  setSpinner(true);
  const outcome = await axios.post(`${url}/negocios/iniciar-sesion`, login);
  console.log(outcome);
  if (outcome.status == 200) {
    if (outcome.data.token) {
      const token = outcome.data.token;
      saveAuth({
        token,
        auth: true,
      });
      setSpinner(false);

      navigation.replace("UsersPanel", true);
    }
  }
} catch (error) {
  if (error.response.status == 500) {
    console.log("error 500");
    setSpinner(false);

    setShowAlert(true);
  } else if (error.response.status == 401) {
    setSpinner(false);

    setShowLoginAlert(true);
  } else {
    setShowIssueAlert(true);
  }
}
```

};

Comment: coloca el codigo en texto para que sea facil corregirlo.

Comment: Listo, ya lo añadí como codigo

Comment: yo le haria una refactorizacion a tu codigo y usaria un contexto para la conexion a la api

Comment: Si reinicio el  servidor de la API haciendole un reboot desde la consola, la app de react native deja de funcionar, pareciera como que el servidor estuviera caido, no recibe ningun respuesta. Pasa lo mismo si cierro la app de react native y luego la vuelvo abrir (en el celular o emulador)

Answer (score 0):

Despues de realizar todo tipo de prueba, pude darme cuenta que el problema no era de la app react native, era de un paquete (pm2) instalado en el servidor que se encarga de mantener activa la api y volver a iniciarla cuando este se reinicia. PM2 arrancaba la API y todo, pero no se porque razon no funcionaba correctamente. Estos fueron los pasos que hice:

Primero

```
pm2 update
```

luego

```
pm2 startup
```

despues

```
pm2 save
```

Luego ejecute el siguiente comando para que mongodb tambien se inicie al arrancar el sistema

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

y problema solucionado.

Muchas gracias a los que contestaron en comentarios